# Two questions, duplicate, both 100k+ views, both 4+ years old

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Here are the two questions:

[How to reset / remove chrome's input highlighting / focus border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/best-way-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border)

[How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Which one should be closed, the one that is least popular, or the one that is not as old, or neither because they're both so popular?

The one that is not as old has a community protection sticker...

Comment: Which one has the better answers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Neither, they're all basically `outline:none;`

Comment: @JamieBarker Then flip a coin.

Comment: @Servy Well _personally_ I feel as though the one that is oldest should stay.

Comment: My argument would point towards keeping the one which is already protected and has 300K more views.

Comment: @Trobbins point towards it being kept open or towards it being closed?

Comment: Sorry, you might've caught my unedited reply. It was mistakenly ambiguous at first -- I clarified it to mean keeping it open, subsequently closing the other one.

Comment: @Trobbins Gotcha, well closing it won't remove it, it should just reference the older one. Although I don't know whether I still see them based upon the amount of rep I have...

Comment: @JamieBarker everyone sees closed questions. Deleted posts can't be seen by <10kers, OP, and mods

Comment: @JamieBarker: Technically `outline: none;` seems to be better than `outline: 0;` (I'm in favour of closing the younger one)

Comment: @codeMagic mods cannot see deleted posts?  ;)

Comment: There's also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1457849/74757. It's older than both of the ones you listed. (Disclaimer: has my highest scoring answer.)

Comment: @Yakk haha...good spot. I meant the only one's who can is 10k+, mods, and OP. I guess I was unsure of how I wanted to say it. But I will leave the incorrect statement for comediac value :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wouldn't this present a good case for merging?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ You are very much correct. Maybe the best way to handle it is to find away to merge them to make it satisfy everyones' needs. Can you close one and add a reference to the other two? So that way all the answers are there but reduce it down to one active one.

Comment: @apaul34208: Are the answers in the dupe so valuable that they need preserving?

Comment: @Kyle: So far it looks like the first one has been closed a duplicate of the second, however I wanted to just throw out there that I knew of another duplicate. The one I answered was slightly more targeted to the situation the asker was in than the two above, but only *very* slightly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair point. This looks like a 6 vs half dozen, both are effectively the same.

Comment: @GrantWinney If they are marked as duplicate of eachother, that would be epic win :)

Comment: @JamieBarker it's happened before.

Comment: Personally, I have to agree with @JaimeBarker assuming that they are *identical* questions.  While the second one has more votes and views, the original poster should really be the recipient of any "goodwill" that SO will provide because of it.  It hurts my incentive to post a question and grow my reputation on SO if I know that someone else can post the same question later, get voted up --> and then my question gets closed as a duplicate?  What would I have to do to keep my question open? Of course, you want the best store of information, but should it hurt the OP in the process?

Comment: Both; increases the odds that someone will find an answer with the particular way they word questions.

Comment: @Morkrom: What does closing both benefit?  (Or keeping both open, which is probably what you meant)  No one is suggesting deleting one, rather marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Neither; they're both over 4 years old at this point.  Those questions have coexisted peacefully for years, with both of them helping a large number of people.  It's manifestly apparent that having both of them present and open is not causing any harm, and it's unclear how closing one or the other would provide a tangible benefit.  There should be some sort of statute of limitations on retrospective pedantry.  Next to doing nothing, the suggestion to make them duplicates of each other is the least-bad option proposed.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, keeping both open is certainly what I meant. With them linking together as Grant reminded me, my notion doesn't matter. It is a real conundrum with no clear answer; to me it seems date of creation and traffic are two important factors.

Maybe asker/answerer pairs should be prompted to "retire" their question in exchange for a scaling amount of reputation either answerer is willing to take as a bribe based on some kind of "time value of reputation" equation.

Comment: @aroth but duplicates are not harmless, the fact that the site hasn't collapsed under the weight of these two is not evidence that they are better both left open

Comment: @BenVoigt - If you're saying that duplicate questions have performance implications (and moreover, such severe performance implications that they could cause the site to collapse), then that's an architectural deficiency for the developers to fix.  Although it's unclear how closing/marking as duplicate would help performance, since both questions would still be retained in the database and since presumably voting/comments/other related activity would remain at about the same level and just be shifted to one question rather than spread over two.  Seems like it's a wash either way.

Comment: @aroth no I'm saying that they have organization of information implications and generally make maintenance harder. When a flaw is found in an answer, or a better explanation is offered, updating all the instances is a huge pain. But if you don't, some visitors will find the inferior version.

Comment: @BenVoigt - That's true if you have a centralized curator, sure.  But SO is more of a wiki model, where everyone can (and does) maintain the content.  Updates across multiple instances happen organically, particularly in the case of heavily-trafficked questions like the ones discussed.  And to properly remove that overhead, it would be necessary to delete one of the instances rather than close it as a duplicate, wouldn't it?  Otherwise it's still possible (and I'd argue, beneficial) to edit the closed/duplicate content over time.

Comment: @aroth the duplicate questions serve as useful sign posts. The answers less so, and arguably they should be deleted. It works better when the duplicate is marked before answers are added, but late making is still better than nothing. And no, SO is not a wiki model.

Comment: @bphilipnyc: It shouldn't hurt much to get your question closed (unless it's a case of "you should've found the other by searching" or "the other is much better worded"). If your questions is closed as a dupe of a later one, this just means that the other has gotten better answers and makes a better canonical post - which is not your fault. And in cases like this, every of the askers has gotten their share of upvotes already.

Comment: @Bergi, respectfully disagree.  I've gotten page views and upvotes years later, so you have to imagine the upvotes and views to perpetuity.  Consider an alternate universe where a mod found the second question the day it was posted and flagged to close it.  If these two questions were identical, the first poster might be due 300 upvotes and counting.   morkrom alluded to a "time value of reputation." Not sure whether it was in half jest, but the concept is clear and true.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Not strictly a wiki model, no.  But _more_ wiki-like than a centrally-curated model like a blog or even a discussion forum.  Anyone with 2,000 rep can edit any content they wish, after all, and that's _very_ wiki-like.  Anyways, the point is/was that while it does take more effort to maintain more questions/answers, that effort is something that doesn't directly fall upon any central or resource-constrained authority.  It's something that arbitrary members of the community will do on a purely voluntary basis, because they can.  In terms of overhead, it's essentially moot.

Comment: If they're both 4 years old and it isn't causing horrendous problems all this time, then there's your answer. Leave it alone.

Comment: Let tem boath be. They survied so long lets make them stay even longer. Its kinda history

Comment: @JamieBarker they are now marked as duplicate of eachother ;-)

Comment: @Fredou they are, one is even marked as a duplicate of another... Unfortunately that other one can't now be marked as duplicate of both of them :(

Comment: I don't get the comments by @aroth and others who think closure is bad. First of all, **nobody is talking about deleting those questions**, we're talking about marking them as dupes. How does that make the questions less helpful? If anything, it makes them more helpful, because there is now a prominent link to even more answers to the same topic. Second, one benefit of closure is preventing new answers that do not add any value; both questions have received very late answers effectively duplicating other answers. So what exactly are you fighting against?

Comment: Or we could ask our friendly mod to do it for us? 0:-) - @MartijnPieters ?

Comment: I cleaned up the circular dupe link.

Comment: @l4mpi I've seen this fear of dupe closing well-written questions "because they'll be deleted" before on other SE sites. I wonder if we need more education about that.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn! I'm guessing we're not able to have all 3 of them marked as dupes of each other? ;)

Comment: @l4mpi - I never said closure is bad.  I'm simply advocating a laissez-faire approach on the basis that these questions have been around for years and clearly are not causing any harm.  In my opinion, nobody has put forth a credible argument for why closing one or the other would be beneficial (if one is left open, you'll still get new answers that don't add value; and voting moots the impact anyways), or a fair method for selecting which one should be closed.  In essence, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @aroth The point is that you could end up at one of them, and not realise there's a better answer on a duplicate question elsewhere in the SO maze. The accepted answer on one of them, is better than the accepted answer on the other.

Comment: But leaving both questions open _is_ broke, @aroth. It's good that they don't cause harm, but that's no reason to not clean things up. If you're not interested in doing so, fine. If you see actual problems with it, such as the wrong question being chosen as a target or specific facets being different enough to warrant separate questions, fine. But "it's currently not harmful" is not an argument for doing nothing. Dupe closure decreases entropy and is always preferable when applicable, at the very least for linking the other question and making sure any new answers are only added to one post.

Comment: @JamieBarker: the end of the duplicate chain has a related posts sidebar that links back.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I personally never look at the linked posts sidebar because often it can contain a lot of noise.