# What to do if there are two old questions that are duplicates of each other?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I found this other question on meta but it doesn't have any answers:
[Two questions, duplicate, both 100k+ views, both 4+ years old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297624/two-questions-duplicate-both-100k-views-both-4-years-old)

I found two questions that are both highly upvoted and are duplicates of each other. The slightly newer one is a better question and has better answers. What is the preferred course of action? Should I flag the new one as a duplicate of the older one? Should I flag the old one as a duplicate of the newer one (since the newer one is better)? Should I just leave them be? Or is there something else I should do to bring attention to them?